# I want to add more than 1 quantity of each product, How?

Tags: php, arrays, session

Can someone teach me how to *add more than 1 quantity for each product?*

Just using `php session/array`.

```
<?php
session_start();
//unset($_SESSION['cart_items'])
// get the product id
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : "";
$name = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : "";
$quantity = isset($_GET['quantity']) ? $_GET['quantity'] : "";

/*
* check if the 'cart' session array was created
* if it is NOT, create the 'cart' session array
*/
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart_items'])){
    $_SESSION['cart_items'] = array();
}

// check if the item is in the array, if it is, do not add
if(array_key_exists($id, $_SESSION['cart_items'])){
// redirect to product list and tell the user it was added to cart
    header('Location: atomyeveningcare4system.php?action=exists&id' . $id . '&name=' . $name);
}else{
    // else, add the item to the array
    $_SESSION['cart_items'][$name]=$name;

    // redirect to product list and tell the user it was added to cart
    header('Location: atomyeveningcare4system.php?action=added&id' . $id . '&name=' . $name);
}
?>
```

I think the problem is from the below code:

```
// check if the item is in the array, if it is, do not add
if(array_key_exists($id, $_SESSION['cart_items'])){
// redirect to product list and tell the user it was added to cart
header('Location: atomyeveningcare4system.php?action=exists&id' . $id . '&name=' . $name);
}
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: So where are you adding 1 to the quantity?

Comment: I dont see you passing a quantity to anything, so I assume the `tomyeveningcare4system.php` assumes you are adding only one of the items each time you add something to the cart

Comment: You are a little short on any useful details in the questions

Comment: I want to add more than 1 quantity.

Comment: I dont have the quantity part of the code. I'm looking for possible ways to add that part of the code. Thanks.